# What is x-frame content?

Tags: web-application, http

I tried scanning  websites for vulnerabilities and found most of them are with low risk x-frame content and "nosniff" what is it exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-Frame-Options HTTP response headers  are useful in that they tell the browser to not allow framing from other domains so that it protects against clikjacking.

For your second question,  you can read from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update?Redirected=true):

> Sending the new X-Content-Type-Options response header with the value
> nosniff will prevent Internet Explorer from MIME-sniffing a response
> away from the declared content-type.